# Parallel sorting of objects takes more time than sequential sorting

Tags: python, multithreading, sorting

I've implemented parallel bitonic sort with Python and I have speed-up more than 3 times compared to the sequential algorithm when sorting integer numbers, but when I'm trying to sort a list of objects parallel sorting takes more time than sequential.

Here is my code for sequential sorting:

```
def bitonic_sort(direction, arr, key=lambda x: x, *args):

    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr

    else:
        first = bitonic_sort(True, arr[:len(arr) // 2], key)
        second = bitonic_sort(False, arr[len(arr) // 2:], key)

        return bitonic_merge(direction, first + second, key)


def bitonic_merge(direction, arr, key=lambda x: x):

    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    else:

        bitonic_swap(direction, arr, key)
        first = bitonic_merge(direction, arr[:len(arr) // 2], key)
        second = bitonic_merge(direction, arr[len(arr) // 2:], key)
        return first + second


def bitonic_swap(direction, arr, key):

    dist = len(arr) // 2

    for i in range(dist):

        if (key(arr[i]) > key(arr[i + dist])) == direction:
            arr[i], arr[i + dist] = arr[i + dist], arr[i]
```

Here is my code where I run my algo in parallel processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools
from bitonic_sort import bitonic_merge, bitonic_sort
from math import log2


def get_args(array, n, m, is_up, key):
    args = []
    j = 0

    while j < n:
        if (j / m) % 2 == 0:
            args.append((is_up, array[j:j + m], key))
        else:
            args.append((not is_up, array[j:j + m], key))
        j = j + m

    return args


def parallel_sort(is_up, array, key, processes, m_count):
    n = len(array)
    processes = 2 ** round(log2(processes))

    m = n // m_count

    pool = Pool(processes=processes)
    args = get_args(array, n, m, is_up, key)
    outputs = pool.starmap(bitonic_sort, args)

    array = list(itertools.chain(*outputs))

    while m <= n:
        m = m * 2
        args = get_args(array, n, m, is_up, key)
        outputs = pool.starmap(bitonic_merge, args)
        array = list(itertools.chain(*outputs))

    return array
```

Here is an object I'm trying to sort

```
class Apartment:
    def __init__(self, host_name="jack"):
        self.price = None
        self.area = None
        self.rate = None
        self.host_name = host_name
        self.randomise()

    def randomise(self):
        self.price = r.randint(100, 1000000000000000000)
        self.area = r.randint(4, 10000)
        self.rate = r.uniform(0, 100)
```

Here is a piece of code where I run both sortings

```
def rand_apartment(n):
    random_list = []
    for _ in range(0, n):
        random_list.append(Apartment())

    return random_list

def res_to_csv(results, file_name, random_list, is_up, key):
    res = []
    run_time_calculation(bitonic_sort, res, random_list, is_up, key=key)
    seq_time = res[0].count_average_time()

    with open(file_name, 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(results[-1].get_info(seq_time))



def calculate_time(func, result, random_list, is_up, key, *args):
    n = len(random_list)
    begin = time.time()

    func(is_up, random_list, key, *args)
    end = time.time()
    time_count = end - begin
    print(f"Total time of sorting {n} elements taken in : {time_count} seconds")

    result.add_time(time_count)


def run_time_calculation(func, results, random_list, is_up, processes=1, m_count=0, key=lambda x: x):
    n = len(random_list)
    res = Result(n, processes, m_count)
    results.append(res)

    for _ in range(0, 1):
        calculate_time(func, res, random_list, is_up, key, processes, m_count)

    print_results(results)

def key_price(x):
    return x.price

def apartment_sorting():
    for i in range(16, 24):
        rand_list = rand_apartment(2 ** i)
        run_time_calculation(parallel_sort, results, rand_list, 1, 8, 8, key_base)
        res_to_csv(results, "exp_apartment", rand_list, 1, key_base)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = []
    # sort_test()
    apartment_sorting()
```

And here is Result class

```
class Result:
    def __init__(self, elements, threads=1, task_size=0):
        self.elements = elements
        self.threads = threads
        self.task_size = task_size
        self.time_counts = []
        self.spead_up = None

    def add_time(self, time):
        self.time_counts.append(time)

    def count_average_time(self):
        return round(sum(self.time_counts) / len(self.time_counts), 11)

    def count_speed_up(self, sequential_speed):
        self.spead_up = sequential_speed / self.count_average_time()

    def print_res(self):
        print("{:<10} {:<4} {:4} {:<17} {:<17}".format(self.elements, self.threads, self.task_size,
                                                       round(self.time_counts[0], 11), self.count_average_time()))

        for i in range(1, len(self.time_counts)):
            print("{:<20} {:<17}".format(" ", round(self.time_counts[i], 11)))

    def get_info(self, sequential_speed):
        self.count_speed_up(sequential_speed)
        return [self.elements, self.threads, self.task_size, self.count_average_time(), round(self.spead_up, 8)]
```

I use 8 processes for sorting because such a quantity gave me the best speed-up for integer sorting. What am I doing wrong with object sorting?

Comment: Multiprocessing in Python requires the use of pickling to send objects between processes. Pickling is slow. Multiprocessing only ends up making sense in situations where the amount of computation is big relative to the amount of data that gets sent between processes. I would bet that sorting is not a place where the amount of computation is big enough for this to be helpful.